# Problema al activar speaker en Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy teniendo problemas al activar el speaker en llamadas Voip especificamente en Android 11. Resulta que uso AudioManager como clase para manejar el speaker, el siguiente codigo anda en versiones de Android 8,9 y 10, pero no anda en versiones de Android 11. Mi pregunta es, hay algo que reemplace el uso del AudioManager y que funcione para Android 11?

```
private fun enableSpeaker() {
        audioManager?.let {
            if (!it.isSpeakerphoneOn) {
                audioManager!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                audioManager!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
                audioManager!!.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
            }
        }

    }

    private fun disableSpeaker() {
        audioManager?.let {
            if (it.isSpeakerphoneOn) {
                audioManager!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                audioManager!!.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente asegura tener el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

actualmente me parece que el modo para aceptar `isSpeakerphoneOn` es `MODE_IN_CALL`:

```
        audioManager!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
        audioManager!!.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
```